# How to Create Basket of Shop site model in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My project is about an online shopping site, using Ruby on Rails to buy phones.
My Database is User, Product, Phone.
I'm trying to create Basket model.

My route:

```
resources :products do
    resources :phone do
      resources :baskets
    end
end
```

And my Code is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :baskets
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   has_many :baskets
end

class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :phone
end
```

When i in the Show action of Product,it Show name of Product and index Phones in this Product,i want to add 1 Phone to Basket,the error is :

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"baskets", :id=>"38", :product_id=>"30"} missing required keys: [:phone_id]
```

I think the problem is :

```
http://localhost:3000/products/30/phone/38
```

It's Product_id = 30,but not Phone_id = 30,in here just is Id = 30.
Someone could help me fix it !

Comment: please give me your ouput from this command: rake routes | grep baskets . And link_to that you have been clicking in

Comment: http://localhost:3000/products/30 , Here is the link when i show Product and Index Phones

Comment: My link_to is :new_product_phone_basket_path

Comment: you need to do it like:
 link_to 'your  text', new_product_phone_basket_path(@product, @basket)

Also I need to say that's recommended to avoid double nested in routes

Comment: @dsounded link should be `new_product_phone_basket_path(@product, @phone)`

Comment: But in the Show action,it show index Phones,when I click 1 phone to show it and show the link to add to Basket,it error.

Comment: Maybe your `@phone` is nil there ?

Comment: Ok,Thank you! It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :products do
  resources :phone do
    resources :baskets
  end
end
```

means you have to have route like this:

```
/products/:product_id/phones/:phone_id/baskets/:basket_id(.:format)
```

Which means, that in `link_to` you should pass the `phone_id` as well:

```
link_to 'show basket' product_phone_basket_path(product_id: @product.id, phone_id: @phone.id, basket_id: @basket.id)
link_to 'New basket' new_product_phone_basket_path(product_id: @product.id, phone_id: @phone.id)
```

Comment: [Bad pattern to use routes nested that deeply](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting)

Comment: @RichPeck thx for pointing this out! In my practice I sometimes allow the 2 levels deep nesting, even though Guides recommended depth is 1. But anyway it is a very good point to mention!

Comment: Yes I was just writing an additional thing for the OP, I upvoted anyway; just though I'd point out what the docs said that's all!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you got it working (I upvoted `@Andrey`'s answer), you'll want to consult your routing structure.

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep. [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting)

--

In your case, I am curious as to why you have `phones` nested inside `products`. Surely a phone *is* a product?

Further, why are you including `resources :baskets`? Surely the basket functionality has nothing to do with whether you're adding a `product`, `phone`, or anything else?

I would personally do the following:

```
resources :products, only: [:index, :show] do
   resources :basket, path:"", module: :products, only: [:create, :destroy] #-> url.com/products/:product_id/
end

#app/controllers/products/basket_controller.rb
class Products::BasketController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_product

   def create
      # add to cart
   end

   def destroy
      # remove from cart
   end

   private

   def set_product
      @product = Product.find params[:product_id]
   end
end
```

---

I've implemented a cart (based on sessions) before ([here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com)).

I can give you the code if you want; I won't put it here unless you want it. It's based on this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model).